# Image is not appearing inside the loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want an image to be added inside the table for every loop run.image is not appearing any help will be appreciated thank u

```js
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
  doc1 = result[i];
  if (doc1.PHOTO == "") {
    var elem1 = document.createElement("img");
    elem1.setAttribute("src", '../common/images/Icon-60.png');
    elem1.setAttribute("height", "60");
    elem1.setAttribute("width", "60");

    var tbody = $("<tbody>").appendTo(table);
    var tr = $("<tr>").appendTo(tbody);
    var td = $("<td>").html(doc1.ENAME).data(doc1).appendTo(tr);
    var tr2 = $("<tr>").appendTo(tbody);
    var td2 = $("<td>").html(elem1).appendTo(tr2);
  }
```

Comment: Is your path incorrect?

Comment: [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) takes a string as an argument, not a HTMLElement.

Comment: i have tried others also its not working and my js implementation rite ???

Comment: why are you creating multiple `tbody`s ?

Comment: @teemu can u provide me a solution to the above

Comment: @david Don't mix vanilla JS and jQuery, create the image as a jQuery object, and append it like you've appended other elements.

Comment: i am new to this any one post me a solution

Comment: What you mean by `.data(doc1)`?

Comment: that storing details for further processing

Comment: You should give a name to your  `data` attribute because now its on get mode and not set, example `.data('details', doc1)`, that will set a data attribute named detals with value `doc1`, check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will solve your problem, but try :

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
     var doc1 = result[i];

     if (doc1.PHOTO == "") {
         var elem1 = "<img src='../common/images/Icon-60.png' height='60' width='60'/>");
         table.append('<tr><td data-name='+doc1+'>'+doc1.ENAME+'</td></tr><tr><td>'+elem1+'</td></tr>');
     }
}
```

Hope  this helps.